# How can i generate a message in selenium IDE for user to do a particular action?

Tags: selenium-ide

when i play my test script then it stops at a page. Is there any command to generate a message to the user to click on the button to proceed to the next page.

Answer (score 1):

you can display you message in an alert window

command:open
Target:/

command:click
target:btnAlert

command:assertAlert

target:I’m blocking!

command:verifyTextPresent
target:Alert is gone.

then continue rest of your test cases